# Can you return multiple values from a python UDF in Redshift?

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

We use JSONB to store elements occasionally. This gets passed to Redshift as a string, that I then parse using a UDF.  For an audit report, I want to present one part of the JSON in one column, and a different part in the other.  Rather than call two UDFs in every row, **can I call one UDF that returns two values?**

As a toy example consider a transactional database where for every row we store the method a customer used to pay.  Some customers can pay with multiple amounts (eg spend down a gift card and then cover the difference in cash), and thus we store a JSON blob in this field.

```
{"Methods": [
   {"Type":"Gift Card", "Amount": 5.74}
    ,{"Type":"Cash", "Amount": 4.26}
],
"Coupons": [
   {"Code": "XHAY12", "Amount":1.22},
   {"Code": "Y123A", "Amount": 4.66}
]}
```

In my report, I want a column (`methods`) that shows the cash amount and a second column `coupons > $5`) that shows whether the transaction got more than $5 off.

I've tried `RETURNS float, int` as well with brackets, braces and parentheses but get generic syntax errors.  Anyone have a suggestion?  Or do I need to suck it up and have separate functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The scalar UDF returns only one value.

You could pass multiple values via a string, but there is no concept of storing values in a variable for further manipulation (eg splitting out values).

From [Creating a Scalar Python UDF](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-udf.html):

> A scalar Python UDF incorporates a Python program that executes when the function is called and returns a **single value**.

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, you can create a UDF that returns JSON with 2 key/value pairs, run it in a subquery and then parse the result with native Redshift function that gets the specific key like this:

```
WITH
udf_subquery as (
    SELECT
     id
    ,your_udf(parameters) as your_udf_json_result
    FROM your_table
)
SELECT
 id
,json_extract_path_text(your_udf_json_result,'key1') as col1
,json_extract_path_text(your_udf_json_result,'key2') as col2
FROM udf_subquery;
```